# Abelian group action exercise

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Let $X$ be a set with $n$ elements and let $G$ be an abelian group acting on $X$ such that: $$(i) \space gx=x \space \forall x \implies g=1,$$ $$(ii) \space \forall x,y \in X, \exists g: gx=y.$$

Show that if $gx=x$ for some $x \in X$, then $g=1$. Deduce that $|G|=n$.

I am not so sure how to attack this problem.

From (i),  if $g \in \bigcap_{x \in X} G_x$, then $g=e_G$, so $\bigcap_{x \in X} G_x=\{e_G\}$.

If there is some $x \in X$ such that $gx=x$ and $y \in X$, by (ii) we have that there is some $g'$ such that $g'x=y$, then $gg'x=gy$, using the fact that $G$ is abelian and the group action property "$(gh).x=g.(h.x)$", we obtain $$gy=gg'x=g'gx=g'x=y $$, by (ii), it must be $g=e_G$.

I got stuck here, I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Fix some $x\in X$, $g \mapsto gx$ is a bijection between the set of elements of $G$, and $X$. Surjection is $(ii)$, you more or less proved injection.

Comment: Thanks, it was much more simpler than I thought, I had the idea that I would have to deal with orbits, quotients and more.

Comment: One elegant way of phrasing this argument is the following: whenever $y = g\cdot x$ then $G_y = G_{gx} = G_x^g = G_x$ because $G$ is abelian. So $\bigcap_{x\in X} G_x = G_{x_0}$ for every $x_0\in X$ by property (ii). But $\bigcap_{x\in X} G_x =1$ by property (i).